# sendRawTransaction results in queued TXs

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, json-rpc, raw-transaction

I attempted to send raw TXs via `eth.sendRawTransaction` API but get stuck. I'm using EthereumJS to generate and sign TXs, and indeed, I can submit TXs through `eth.sendRawTransactin`, but the TXs always result in queued (non-processable, per geth doc).

I called `eth.sendRawTransactin` from a geth console, and it returns a hash as usual. I can get transaction details by that hash:

```
> eth.getTransaction(hash)
{
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0x89b44e4d3c81ede05d0f5de8d1a68f754d73d997",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 50000000000,
  hash: "0x69b4a0768e72c3a679a1ae6fb490a831509c3c0a04674b646362d0a3d74689a4",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 10,
  to: "0xb7e13de69228c37cdff506ea474f31343af33c05",
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: 2000000
}
```

But the TXs are queued forever:

```
> txpool.status
{
  pending: 0,
  queued: 5
}
```

Also sending address is rich enough to pay off the gas:

```
> eth.getBalance("89b44e4d3c81ede05d0f5de8d1a68f754d73d997")
20000000000000000020
```

To compare, this is a valid transaction (created and sent by some client)

```
> eth.getTransactionFromBlock(11)
{
  blockHash: "0x41919469d7ed9232adbcacc820e61ad508b30eb5fc4750d3cebd748c22b110b8",
  blockNumber: 11,
  from: "0xb7e13de69228c37cdff506ea474f31343af33c05",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 50000000000,
  hash: "0xa4d4a22aa1fed291a7da00e24304f7093b4fc09b1c6a18692e4240d6d913d674",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 4,
  to: "0x89b44e4d3c81ede05d0f5de8d1a68f754d73d997",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 20000000000000000000
}
```

Since geth can parse them, the format of my TXs has to be correct. I guess the only thing left is the signature. But I'm pretty sure the TX has been properly signed.

Is there a way to get more information about why a TX can't be processed? I'm using `geth` on my own blockchain so I can modify the source code if that helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the transaction is queued but not executable, that means that there's a nonce gap between your latest executed transaction and the next in line that's waiting to run.

If you pull in a develop version of geth, it has two extra txpool API endpoint (txpool.content and txpool.inspect) that allows you to list the contents of pending and queue. My guess is that your script misses a nonce, producing non-executable transactions.

Comment: Super! Can you point me to the reference about this rule of nonce?

Comment: http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf Page 7, section 6, first paragraph, bullet point 3.