# How exactly does the "pending" block tag work?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm

I have been trying to read up more on the block tags provided by the [JSON-RPC API](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#default-block):

> When requests are made that act on the state of Ethereum, the last
> default block parameter determines the height of the block.
>
> The following options are possible for the defaultBlock parameter:
>
> HEX String - an integer block number
>
> String "earliest" for the earliest/genesis block
>
> String "latest" - for the latest mined block
>
> String "safe" - for the latest safe head block
>
> String "finalized" - for the latest finalized block
>
> String "pending" - for the pending state/transactions

I have also read through these posts, but was not satisfied with how much I understood it:

[eth.pendingTransactions vs eth.getBlock('pending').transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6720/eth-pendingtransactions-vs-eth-getblockpending-transactions)

[What's the difference between "pending" block and txpool?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42598/whats-the-difference-between-pending-block-and-txpool)

I am still a bit confused on how exactly the `pending` tag differs from the `latest` tag. From the above posts, I have noted that the pending tag constructs a "most-likely" block and then simulates against that as if it were mined. Is this always the case for all nodes?

Does this mean if I were to call `eth_estimateGas` using the `pending` tag, I would get a better estimate of what the final gas cost will be, rather than simulating against `latest`? If so, then surely it is better to always simulate against `pending` rather than `latest`.

Similarly, if I were to call `eth_getLogs` with the `pending` tag, would this pull logs from transactions that haven't been included yet?

I am open to more technical answers if possible, since I am not a beginner, just curious how exactly this works.